# Encryption/Decryption results in replacement and incorrect characters at start of string

Tags: php, encryption

Here are my encrypt and decrypt functions

```
public function encrypt($text){
        $key = hash("md5", KEY);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
        $result = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
        return $result;
}

public function decrypt($text){
        $key = hash("md5", KEY);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
        $result = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, $key, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));    
        return $result;
}
```

When encryption is run on a JSON string to be stored as a text file and then retrieved and decrypted the front section of the resulting string has replacement and/or incorrect characters:

**Expected:**

> {"players":[{"label":"...

**Actual:**

> �Ӹ�!G@${�W�Rՙ�bel":"...

If it makes any difference the actual placement/incorrect chars are different each time I refresh the page on the same file.

Comment: try to remove the encoding layer and see if the base64_decode returns the same data

Comment: @G_G do you mean the encryption layer?

Comment: exactly, I mean removing the encryption layer altogether and see if at least base64 is working as expected

Comment: I just tried it, the base64 returns exactly what is expected

Comment: ok, now remove the base64 layer, leave the encryption there and try to encode/decode a known binary sequence, let's say "0x01,0x02,0x03". Do not use any string function to see the output, do a byte-wise test e.g. testin[0] == testout[0] && testin[1] == testout[1] && testin[2] == testout[2] and so on...

Comment: How do I create a binary sequence? Is it an array of "0b01", "0b02", "0b03"? I've never had to use binary in php before.

Comment: $teststring = "abcdefg"; would be ok to...

Comment: Ok so after some playing around the problem was I was regenerating the IV rather than prepending it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this...

The IV needs to be prepended to the file before encoding, like so:

```
public function encrypt($text){
    $key = hash("md5", KEY);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $result = base64_encode($iv.mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    return $result;
}
```

Then when decrypting take the IV from the decoded string and use it to decrypt, like so:

```
public function decrypt($text){
    $key = hash("md5", KEY);
    $decode = base64_decode($text);
    $iv = substr($decode, 0, 16);
    $decrypt = substr($decode, 16);
    $result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, $key, $decrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return $result;
}
```